# get a return value from a flask function into another python file (calling a flask function from not flask python file)

Tags: python, flask

I have to take input from a web page in python. I am using flask for that. I want to return the input it got. I want to call that flask function into another file that does not use flask, just python file.
Example: the following code is in the inputpage.py

```
@app.route('/topic', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def topic_input():
    res = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not request.form['t1'] and not request.form['t2'] :
            res = 'please fil the form'
            # print(result)
        else:
            try:
                term = request.form['t1']
                t2 = int(request.form['t2'])
                res='Good'

            except BaseException as error:
                res = 'error: {}'.format(error)
                # print(result)
    #return render_template('topic.html', articles=res_dic, result=res)
    return(term,t2)
```

In another file lets say test.py I try to call the above function ,

```
from inputpage import topic 
print(topic_input())
```

But I get the following error:
raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.

I wonder how I can do such thing.
Your help is appreciated :)

Comment: What exactly do you try to achieve? Do you want to write a test for your Flask function? Or do you want ot reuse the code somewhere else? Maybe in a module, or for a command line application?

Comment: I want to call this method in another file to receive the input. Did you see the example? I want to call the topic_input into the test file.

Comment: Your topic input relies on a web request - and when you call it from another function, there is no web request. So, it is still unclear what you try to achieve.

Comment: I want to get the input that retrieved by topic_input function into inputpage.py; you see the     return(term,t2) which return the input texts
. I could be wrong, but wonder what the best way to do in such case?

Comment: I think there is still a misunderstanding - your `topic_input` needs a request in order to work - no request - no result. When you import `topic_input` in another module (file) and call it there without a request, it cannot work. Maybe you want to do it the other way round. Import some other function and use it in your `topic_input` route.

Comment: Thanks J.G. I was trying the other way as it makes sense. I got some errors since I am using genism model in other function that to be called into topic_input. I will figure out what to. But if there is an easier way , please let me know